# SSH Protocol mismatch

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, duplicity

I have a very strange problem. I have two servers, namely `daytona`, which serves as a storage server with a raid array. I WOL it when I want to back up to it. The second server is `testarossa` which runs my services. It is the latter that I want to backup daily using duplicity. Both machines run Ubuntu Server 14.04, fully up-to-date.

I have written a script to WOL the machine and then execute the duplicity backup each day on a fixed time.

The import part of the backupscript is shown below. The backup runs as user `root` on `testarossa` and backups over SSH via `backupper` on `daytona`. Then it shuts down via `ssh` using user `christophe` on `daytona`.

I have configured ssh keys on `testarossa` so I can ssh into `daytona` using `backupper` and `christophe`. I can execute the commands from the script just fine, and even execute the script in the shell as well (`./script.sh`).

I have added the script in the cronjobs using:

```
0 10  * * * /bin/bash /root/scripts/dailybackup >> /var/log/backup.daily.log 2>&1
```

Each time the cronjob runs I get the following error:

```
BackendException: ssh connection to backupper@192.168.1.120:22 failed: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I have, suggested on `#ubuntu-server`, tried `echo "" | nc 192.168.1.120 22` and that returns the following error:

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
Protocol mismatch.
```

This led me to believe that I had to upgrade `daytona` which I did. There was an upgrade for the `gnu-openssl` package and then the cronjob ran fine. But now it doesn't anymore.

I am out of ideas on how to debug this. I have too little experience to fix it. Any pointers?

## Script

```
serverip=192.168.1.120
servermac=14:DA:E9:4C:6E:17
attempts=50
sourcedir="/"
targetdir="sftp://backupper@192.168.1.120//mnt/raidarr0/backups/testarossa/duplicity/daily"
encryptkey="AC7A8F8C"
keep="1M"
sudouser="christophe" 
fullbackup=""

## Load in the passphrase file env variable
. /root/.passphrase
export PASSPHRASE

## Do the snapshot backup
if [ "$fullbackup" == "full" ]; then
    $(which duplicity) full --encrypt-key "$encryptkey" --exclude /srv --exclude /usr --exclude /cdrom --exclude /lib64 --exclude /bin --exclude /sbin --exclude /boot   --exclude /dev --exclude /proc --exclude /sys --exclude /tmp --exclude /run --exclude /mnt --exclude /media --exclude /lost+found "$sourcedir" "$targetdir"
else
    $(which duplicity)      --encrypt-key "$encryptkey" --exclude /srv --exclude /usr --exclude /cdrom --exclude /lib64 --exclude /bin --exclude /sbin --exclude /boot   --exclude /dev --exclude /proc --exclude /sys --exclude /tmp --exclude /run --exclude /mnt --exclude /media --exclude /lost+found "$sourcedir" "$targetdir"
fi

echo "Backup to target completed."

## Remove older backups. We only want to backup 30 days. 
# (We have a full every month)
$(which duplicity) remove-older-than "$keep" --force "$targetdir"
echo "Removal of stale backups completed"
## Shut down the machine using a sudo account. Expects the user to have a key installed for this.
ssh "$sudouser"@"$serverip" "sudo shutdown -h now"
echo "Shutdown command issued to remote machine"
```

### Follow up:

1) The script has a function which waits for the host to be ping-able. So it only starts backing up when the host has fully booted. (This script ran fine for over a year on a different machine with Debian.)

2) The script runs fine in the shell of the root indeed.

3) And no, I do not have a proxy command in either setting files.

4) I have tried running the command using `sudo /bin/bash /root/scripts/dailybackup` and now, for some reason, it asks me to verify the authenticity of the host (with `yes/no`). So now it seems like the duplicity command is not using my `known_hosts` file?

Comment: No, the protocol mismatch is just because "echo" doesn't speak ssh protocol (sshd is confused by that LF character echo sends to it). The fact that sshd outputs a banner is inconsistent with your "Connection refused" error though. Do you have a ProxyCommand configured in /etc/ssh_config or ~/.ssh/config?

Comment: Did I understand correctly: `/bin/bash /root/scripts/dailybackup` works fine when run manually but does give `connection refused` when run via cron?

Comment: Is the script to fast? In other words, is the backup being performed before the host is fully started and initialized? A `connection refused` message may appear if the `sshd` service is not started/operational yet on the target host.

Comment: That a machine is 'pingable' does not mean that network dependent services are initialized yet. To test if `sshd` is running, consider using `nc -vz 192.168.1.120 22`

Comment: I will temporarily test it with a sleep of 1 minute.

Comment: Besides, if the backup host is not in the `known_hosts` for the backup user, copy the entry from the root user to the backup user or `su` into the context of the backup user and try to `ssh` to the backup host to get the entry into the `known_hosts` file of the backup user.

Comment: I have done all that before. So that is one of the reasons I'm assuming that duplicity has its own `known_hosts` file.

Answer (score 1):

The error "Protocol mismatch." is very simple: nc doesn't use the ssh protocol to connect to the remote address and port.

Regarding the actual problem: is backupper user connecting via ssh keys? If so, where are the keys kept?

What I think is happening is that you test your script with another user than root.

Try to run your script as root like this and see if it fails also:

```
sudo /bin/bash /root/scripts/dailybackup
```

Others had the same error because of [IP conflict](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30080/how-to-solve-connection-refused-errors-in-ssh-connection)

Comment: See follow up. The machine now asks me to verify the key. How odd. These should be in the `known_hosts` file..

Comment: add those options to your ssh command and check again "-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"

Comment: They keys are kept in the user's respective folder as one would expect. So root has his public key in `/home/(christophe|backupper)/.ssh/authorized_keys` . So yes, via ssh keys.

Comment: The last error is not about ssh keys, but because the system doesn't trust the ssh host. You either run once the command and reply with "y" when prompted, or use the above parameters for ssh to trust all hosts